# Transfer cell values from different columns and sheets from multiple excel files with same structure into a single dataframe

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a reporting sheet in excel that contains a set of datapoints that I want to compile from multiple files with the same format into a master dataset. 
The initial step I undertook was to extract the data points I need from multiple sheet into one pandas dataframe. See the steps below

I initally imported the excel file and parsed it

```
import pandas as pd
xl = pd.ExcelFile(r"C:\Users\Nicola\Desktop\ISP 2016-20 Ops-Technical Form.xlsm")
df = xl.parse("FSL, WASH, DRM") #name of sheet #1
```

Then I located the data points needed for synthesis

```
a=df.iloc[5:20,3:5]
a1=df.iloc[6:9,10:12]
b=df.iloc[31:35,3:5]
b1=df.iloc[31:35,10:12]
```

Then I concatenated and equalised columns positioning to maintain the whole list of values within the same column:

```
dfcon=pd.concat(([a,b]))
dfcon2=pd.concat(([a1,b1]))
new_cols = {x: y for x, y in zip(dfcon.columns, dfcon2.columns)}
dfcont2=dfcon2.append(dfcon.rename(columns=new_cols))
```

And lastly created a dataframe with the string of values I need

```
master=pd.DataFrame(dfcont2)
finalmaster=master.transpose()
```

The next two steps I wish to pursue are:
1) Replicate the same code for 50 excel files 
2) Compile all string of values from this set of excel files into one single pandas dataframe without running this code over again and compile manually by exporting it into excel.

Any support would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution that works for me, thank you for the input, jezrael. 
To further explain:

1) Imported the files with same structure from my Desktop directory, parsed and selected the Excel sheet from which data can be extracted from different locations (iloc)

```
import glob
dfs = []
for f in glob.glob('C:/Users/Nicola/Desktop/OPS Form/*.xlsm'):
    df = pd.ExcelFile(io=f, sheet_name=1) 
    df = df.parse("FSL, WASH, DRM")
    a=df.iloc[5:20,3:5]
    a1=df.iloc[7:9,10:12]
    b=df.iloc[31:35,3:5]
    b1=df.iloc[31:35,10:12]
    c=df.iloc[50:56,3:5]
    c1=df.iloc[38:39,10:12]
    d=df.iloc[57:61,3:5]
    e=df.iloc[63:71,3:5]
```

2) Concatenated and repositioned columns order to compose the first version of the dataframe (output)

```
    dfcon=pd.concat(([a,b,c,d,e]))
    dfcon2=pd.concat(([a1,b1,c1]))        
    new_cols = {x: y for x, y in zip(dfcon.columns, dfcon2.columns)}
    dfcont2=dfcon2.append(dfcon.rename(columns=new_cols))
    dfs.append(dfcont2.T)
```

3) Output presented the same string of values but repeated twice [same label and form-specific entry] from recursive data pull-outs linked to iloc locations.

```
output = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

4) This last snippet simply allowed me to extract the label only once and to select all entries ordered in odd numbers. With the last concatenation, I generated the dataframe I seeked, ready to be processed analytically.

```
a=output[2:3]
b=output[1::2]
pd.concat([a,b], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe need loop by file names created by `glob` and last [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) together (all files have same structure):

```
import glob

dfs = []
for f in glob.glob('*.xlsm'):
    df = pd.read_excel(io=f, sheet_name=1)    

    a=df.iloc[5:20,3:5]
    a1=df.iloc[6:9,10:12]
    b=df.iloc[31:35,3:5]
    b1=df.iloc[31:35,10:12]

    dfcon=pd.concat(([a,b]))
    dfcon2=pd.concat(([a1,b1]))
    new_cols = {x: y for x, y in zip(dfcon.columns, dfcon2.columns)}

    dfcont2=dfcon2.append(dfcon.rename(columns=new_cols))
    dfs.append(dfcont2.T)

out = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Could you would advise on how to parse each f? I could do it individually for each sheet, but is there a more elegant way. And I still get the labels of each compiled observation repeated. How can I merge all labels that I would get in dfcont2 also in dfs? Thanks